# Removing a character from string in Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, automation, capybara

I am new to Rspec and I am facing a little issue.

```
text = page.find(:xpath,"some xpath").text
```

the code line above gets the value from a html element i.e. 15% or any other value under 100, I want to remove % sign from the value after and getting it to use for comparison. Can anybody help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String#sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) to replace it:

```
'15%'.sub('%', '') #=> '15'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use gsub in case there is more than one occurrence:

```
'15%%%'.gsub('%', '') #=> '15'
```